# Salesforce Code Deployment : ANT & Changesets learning via developer edition

Tags: deployment, change-set, ant

I am trying to learn salesforce code deployment process.

I believe deploying code via ANT & Changesets are the most common ways to deploy your changes into Production.

I would like to get a hands-on (self-learning) with these tools as such is it possible to learn about these tools with my developer edition itself ?

Comment: also you can deploy from eclipse force.com IDE; changesets won't allow you to delete components from production.

Comment: There are also third party tools for moving changes around your Salesforce orgs....I highly recommend you check them out when you run into issues with Change Sets or the ant tools. Full disclosure that I lead the team, but at https://gearset.com we are trying to build the best Salesforce deployment service out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try self learning with two sample developer orgs .Try moving some metadata and code from one developer to another developer org .

There is a small video that can help you on how to achieve this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5UlWurQzHQ

The installation steps are documented below

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/Content/forcemigrationtool_install.htm

The documentation on how to use this is as below

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can use developer edition very well to get hands-on on Salesforce Deployment experience.

Here are some quick links :

1. [Changeset Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qy8oV99iAM) , [Change set overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets.htm&language=en_US) and [Best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_best_practices.htm)
2. [Using Eclipse for Metadata Migration](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster)
3. [Basics of ANT Migration tool](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-migration-tool-ant/)

Some advance reference materials :

4. [Automated backup of Salesforce Org using ANT](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/automated-daily-backup-using-ant-migration-tool-and-git/)
5. [Using Jenkins for Continuous integration](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/continuous-integration-in-salesforce-using-jenkins-and-git-video-tutorial/)